# How to manage jquery-datatable styles for more than one table?

Tags: datatables

I am working with jquery-datatables and want to add a background color to the header but I have several datatables and when using the following css code, changes apply to all tables equally.

How can I apply different changes for each separate table?

```css
div.dataTable thead th,table.dataTable thead tr {
    background-color: #ffeb3b;
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Each DataTable should have a unique ID assigned to the HTML: `<table id="my_table_1" ... >`.  You can use those as the targets of your CSS: `table#my_table_1`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I tryed the way that tu mention, but it only change the color for the data ("td" tags), not for the head ("thead", "th" or "tr" tags) any idea what else can I try?.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to show us your different tables, your different CSS styles, and how you are trying to manage the header background colors. In other words, a [mre]. Without that information, there is nothing I can suggest, because targeting unique IDs should work, unless there is something unusual about your situation.